# How to delete files containing certain string using batch file in Windows?

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

My Panasonic camera uses its stupid PHOTOfunSTUDIO to import photos. It creates folders by the name of the date when photos are taken, and imports photos into those folders respectively. So far so good. But If I import again before removing all old pictures from camera, the old ones will be imported again by adding a name suffix (002),(003),..., no mater how I change the settings of that software.

My question: how to remove all the files that having name suffixes from those folders?

For example, this is one folder:

```
D:\Photos\2011\2011-12-01>dir  /b
20111201_184550(002).cont
20111201_184550(002).iis
20111201_184550(002).m2ts
20111201_184550(002).tmb
20111201_184550.cont
20111201_184550.iis
20111201_184550.m2ts
20111201_184550.tmb
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, maybe I was stupid. It does not need any batch:

```
del /s *(00?).*
```

Answer (score 6):

```
del *"("*")".* /s
```

The " " around the ( mean that it is a character instead of being part of the delete command.
/s - includes all subfolders

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/del.mspx?mfr=true

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

you can easily use wildcard asterix (*) to search like any search utility

-- search current folder when directory is not specified

```
del Search_Service_Application_1_*.trn
```

-- specifying specific folder working even if you are in another drive

```
del d:\test\*copy*.txt
```