# How to delete directories containing certain string using batch file in Windows?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, delete-file

From

[How to delete files containing certain string using batch file in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513510/how-to-delete-files-containing-certain-string-using-batch-file-in-windows)

I learned how to mass delete files which contain certain strings. What I did is

```
del *(2)* /f /s
```

but this did not delete directories. It only delete files.

How can I also mass-delete directories which contain certain strings?

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard Windows command to delete files and directories on the same level. `DEL` is used for files, `RMDIR` / `RD` is used for directories (however it can delete files *within* directories).

`RMDIR` / `RD` does not work with wildcards, so you need to use a `FOR` loop. As it is, the below code will print out the commandos to delete the directories in your question. Remove the `ECHO` when you're confident the deletion will do what you want.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S "*(2)*"') DO (
    ECHO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
)
```

You can also reduce this to a one-liner...

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S "*(2)*"') DO ECHO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
```

...and if you want to execute it directly in the shell (as opposed to from a `.bat` file), do:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S "*(2)*"') DO ECHO RMDIR /S /Q "%G"
```

Flags explanation:

- `FOR`

  - `/F`: iterate over a fileset
- `DIR`

  - `/B`: bare format (needed so it works with `FOR`)
  - `/AD`: filter for directories
  - `/S`: work recursive
- `RMDIR`

  - `/S`: work recursive
  - `/Q`: quiet mode